# SQlite LIMIT and [ROW_NUMBER]

Tags: sqlite

In SQL this command works ok:

**Query**

```
SELECT TOP 20 * FROM 
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY t0.ProductId) AS [ROW_NUMBER], *
    FROM Product AS [t0]
)  AS [t1]
WHERE [t1].[ROW_NUMBER] > 0 * 20;
```

Now I try the same with `SQLite`. I know that I must replace `TOP` with `LIMIT`, but don't know where to put it.

I always get something like

**Error**

> SQLite error near "(": syntax error" or "SQLite error near "*": syntax error".

And I am not sure that the command `[ROW_NUMBER]` or `ROW_NUMBER()` works in `SQlite`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Query**

```
SELECT *, 
(
    SELECT COUNT(*) 
    FROM Product b  
    WHERE a.ProductId >= b.ProductId
) AS rnum
FROM Product a LIMIT 20;
```

**Screen Shot**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

See the [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#limitoffset):

```
SELECT *
FROM Product
LIMIT 20
OFFSET 0  -- optional
```

Answer (score 0):

SQlite doesn't support `TOP`. That is sql-server syntax. You have to use `limit 20` instead.